Identify Zener Diode with label of SF on an Antminer S21 hashboard
I have the following Zener Diode I need to replace, but I'm not sure how to identify it as there are 100s of diodes out there. The only marking I see is SF. How does one go about identifying this stuff?




How do you know it's a Zener diode?


How does one go about identifying


Use google search: SOD-123 "SF" marking
Use one of the many marking code search sites like

Hotenda.com
smd.yooneed.one
alldatasheet.com



The results here are basically all B0540W Schottky diodes by different manufacturers. Here is one made by Diodes Inc:


(Source: lcsc.com)
Note that the one I linked is in a SOD-323 package, but SOD-123 is also available. Since you didn't give any dimensions, I'm not sure what package yours is in.
